# making two different class names together in the same h3 tag in code retrieved from remote source

Tags: php, html

i am working getting the html source code from remote page then removing some `tbody` s from

the source the echo it in my page this all works well but the problem i am stuck at is that i

want to put two class name in the same `h3` tag as this is the only way the code can display

properly in my page

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://lsh.streamhunter.eu/static/section35.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo $doc->saveHTML(); // save new HTML
?>
```

how i can make the two class names `eventtitle` and `lshjpane-toggler lshtitle`

to be in the same h3 tag no each in separate tag

edit: to make it clear look at this code

`<h3 class="lshjpane-toggler lshtitle eventtitle150909" onclick="getEvent(150909)"></h3><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="middle" width="20px;" height="20px;" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px; background: url(/images/stories/kr.png) no-repeat scroll  center;"></td>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;"><span class="lshstart_time">12:00</span></td>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;"><span class="lshevent">Daekyo Kangaroos Women  - Incheon Red Angels Women</span></td>
                                        </tr></table><h3 id="preloadevent150909" style="display:none" class="preload-lshjpane-toggler"></h3>`

it will display properly only if the `</h3>` before `<table` removed

how can i remove this tag from the code retrieved from the remote page

Comment: how can i remove the h3 closing tag from the code retrieved from the remote page

Answer (score 0):

If I were on Your place I would store the whole page in some variable before display.

```
$page = $doc->saveHTML();
```

then repalce the `</h3><table`, with `<table`.

```
$page = str_replace('</h3><table', '<table', $page);
```

then echo the result:

```
echo $page; // echo $page
```

But I'm afraid that the main problem is that `<table>` can not be putted into `<h3>` and that's probably why You don't get the code that You wish to have.